# setting the row inactive by getting its database id

Tags: php, mysql

delete.php

I want to change my delete that when i delete a record on my website it will not be permanently deleted on my database I already made an additional column(`status INTEGER NOT NULL DEFAULT 0`) that when 0=inactive(deleted) 1=active

```
 <?php
 include_once 'dbconfig.php';

 if($_POST['del_id']){
   $id = $_POST['del_id'];  
  $stmt=$db_con->prepare("DELETE FROM tblsales WHERE id=:id");
  $stmt->execute(array(':id'=>$id));    
 }
?>
```

thanks for the help I'm just starting my php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply change your query to an update query:

```
  $stmt=$db_con->prepare("UPDATE tblsales set status=0 WHERE id=:id");
  $stmt->execute(array(':id'=>$id));
```

BTW: I think your Default should be 1 (active)?

Comment: status has been change but the data is still visible on my website

Comment: @JobSanjuan you have also to check the column if you read the data